# Creating MovieClip 'components' that don't add to file size in Flash AS2/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, custom-component, filesize

I want to create a re-usable Flash MovieClip (component maybe?) that can be dragged and dropped from the library onto the Flash IDE stage (for an example, a "stop all movieclips timer component").

I've created some attractive vector icon graphics for visual reference, so that when it's dragged onto the stage, the developer can visually see the component on the stage, similar to what Google does with it's DoubleClick components. It's not important for these icon graphics to be seen at runtime however, and I'd like their visual portions to not be compiled at runtime to save on filesize.

I'm often asked to create visually rich Flash units in extremely small file sizes. So basically I want my movieclip icon components to not add to filesize (except for the code portion), not compile and render visually but still have the code within them run.

How can I achieve this? Would creating them as components do anything for my issue? Is this even do-able?

Comment: I really like this question, I have some ideas on how this would work so I'll test them out and let you know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Components are definitely the best way to achieve visually represented imported code, however it would be much easier, more compatible and more reliable to just use an imported code library...

Make a seperate .as file, put it in com/mycompany/animation in your swf folder (or use a global classpath), and add this code:

```
package com.mycompany.animation {
    class MyTimerUtils {
        public static function stopAllClipsAfterTime(ms){
            setInterval(MyTimerUtils.stopAllClips, ms);
        }
        public static function stopAllClips(){
            //etc
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it in a project, just put this code on frame 1 of your main timeline:

```
import code.mycompany.animation.MyTimerUtils;
MyTimerUtils.stopAllClipsAfterTime(3000); // 3 seconds
```

What could be easier? If another developer wants to know if a piece of code is implemented they need only look at the first few lines of code.

Comment: I should add, components are pretty unpredictable and convoluted to produce, not to mention having poor source control/updating options, and no need to worry about graphics hogging filesize

Comment: I concur that, as far as code goes, writing classes, as you demonstrated, is usually best (though I shy away from the misnomer "best practice," as there are always exceptions). To clarify, however, for anyone who finds this via Google, components and symbols are still the best way to create VISUAL elements, unless you prefer to do everything code-only.

Comment: I might be lacking knowledge on these "components" or at least it doesn't sound familiar to me unless you are referring to design patterns, but I would question how this answer fits. Would this be placed instead of his asset? Or is this being used to remove the asset at the `stopAllClips()`. Either way, I was thinking a JSFL script could easily accomplish this by removing the child asset and then running a compile or something along those lines (assuming this is all in the IDE).

Comment: Agreed @JasonMc90, components and symbols are the best way to visually represent code on the Stage.

Comment: @p1on, yes, placed instead of an asset. Perhaps my answer doesn't address component creation, but I still maintain it's better approach for the described situation. JSFL I don't know enough about to really comment on